# How can I use Facebook SDK or graph api to get user had liked a Facebook fan page

Tags: facebook

I would like to develop button which can like a facebook fan page

But when I search from google, Facebook used to have a edge.create event but it had already been deprecated and the appEvent will also deprecated in July 2022, may anyone has any idea on how to achieve or Facebook now do not allow to query for that?

and I try to do research on the facebook development document

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/object/likes/#------2

the closest solution seems like this one  I created a fan page for replace the object id by the fan page id but fail and got the following error

```
Application does not have the capability to make this API call
```

Is there anyone have any idea?

Comment: You can not make your own like button, pages can not be liked via API. You can only use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

Comment: Hi @CBroe, thank you for your comment, for the like button part, is there any way to track whether the user had clicked and liked now, since facebook used to have a subscribe event function called 'edge.create' for tracking but now seem it has been removed.

Comment: No, they removed that, because it was used for "like gating", and that is not allowed any more.

Comment: noted with thanks